# How to split the string with delimiter and swap the substring's position in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, split, shift

This is the scenario,

For example, we have a list of files named as a.txt,b.txt,...z.txt. Goal is to name them as txt.a,txt.b,txt.c.....txt.z

Input:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
...
...
z.txt
```

Output:

```
txt.a
txt.b
txt.c
...
...
txt.z
```

I tried this one-liner and got the desired output.
One-liner

```
ls -l *.txt | awk -F " " '{print $9}' | awk -F "." '{str1 = $2; str2 = "."; str3 = $1; str4 = str1 str2 str3; print str4}'
```

Ask:
**Could someone help if there is still any better way in bash to achieve this functionality?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions/understanding:

- the objective is to rename the files (the question mentions *`Goal is to name them as ...`* but there is no mention of the `mv` command ... ???)
- all file names contain a single period
- we want to switch the before-period/after-period portions of the file names to create new file names
- no files exist with the new file name (eg, we don't currently have files named `a.txt` and `txt.a`)

One idea using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which allows us to eliminate the overhead of sub-process calls:

```
for fname in *.txt
do
    new_fname="${fname#*.}.${fname%.*}"
    echo mv "${fname}" "${new_fname}"
done
```

For files names `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` this generates:

```
mv a.txt txt.a
mv b.txt txt.b
mv c.txt txt.c
```

Once OP is satisfied with the results the `echo` can be removed and the script should perform the actual `mv`/rename.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is the last column, and the files have a single dot, you can use a single awk to split on a dot and print the 2 parts in reverse.

Using `$NF` matches the last field.

```
ls -l *.txt | awk '
{
    split($NF, a, ".")
    print a[2] "." a[1]
}'
```

If there should be 2 parts after the split, you can check the result from split:

```
ls -l *.txt | awk '
{
    n=split($NF, a, ".")
    if (n == 2) print a[2] "." a[1]
}'
```

Or as an alternative using sed and 2 capture groups printed in reverse, using `ls -1` to list one file per line.

```
ls -1 *.txt | sed -E 's/^([^.]+)\.([^.]*)$/\2.\1/'
```

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, that is a good read. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl based `rename` command is available, please try:

```
rename 's/^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$/$2.$1/' *.txt
```

The renaming rule is that of Perl's substitution expression
using regex:

- `^` matches (anchors) the start of the filename.
- `([^.]+)` matches a sequence of any characters except a dot.
  Then the matched substring can be referred by `$1` due to the surrounding parentheses.
- `\.` matches a dot.
- `([^.]+)` again. Now it is referred by `$2`.
- `$` matches (anchors) the end of the filename.
- `$2.$1` is the substitution part, which swaps the two substrings
  across the dot.

Please note there are two different commands named `rename`. One is
Perl based, the other is not. You can identify it by
seeing the manpage. If it includes the word `perlexpr`, it is Perl based.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in [a-z].txt; do mv "$f" "txt.${f%.*}"; done
```